# When trying to open Google spreadsheet Apps Script, an error occurs and it cannot be opened

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

Apps Script cannot be opened and a text similar to the following is displayed.
Is this just me? Or is it a general problem with Google?

```
Google Docs encountered an error. Please try reloading this page, or coming back to it in a few minutes.

To learn more about the Google Docs editors, please visit our help center.


We're sorry for the inconvenience.
- The Google Docs Team
```

I looked it up on the internet. But I didn't get any answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with google - there has been number of reports found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B%20status:open%20type:bug%20). Updates from google are being posted [here](https://support.cloud.google.com/portal/system-status?product=WORKSPACE)